# OpenJDK 11 - Is there a way to specify which SSLExtensions to exclude/include in your application?

Tags: java, ssl

[SSLExtension.java on Github (AdoptJDK)](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/SSLExtension.java)

I'm seeing SSLExtensions defined here, but I'm not seeing how there's a way to globally include or exclude certain extensions from being used with a library such as Apache HttpClient.

Comment: Your planning to build your own JDK?

Comment: No, I'm looking to provide some functionality to apache's httpclient that allows me to be able to control all aspects of a SSL handshake including which extensions are allowed, TLS version, ciphers, etc.